# Bootstrap Left & Right Div Block Alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any class available in Bootstrap to make Div Block to make Left, Right and showing form control when Screen getting narrow or on a Mobile view that Left, Right View would go Up, Down. One other main thing is that only the div blocks are left and right align but each control in the div blocks should be left aligned. Searching in BS document but not able find anything.

***Please Ignore Blue Div in 1st Image (Accidental)**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes there are col-xl, col-lg, col-md,col-sm,col-xs

Answer (score 2):

Yes obviously, we have row and columns to achieve this layout

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                Div Left
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                Div Right
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Bottom Panel
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```